# Python SQL query result

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I'm verifying user input against a SQLite3 DB. However, I can't get the if/else statement to work. The result is always "Not found". What is wrong with this code? I know the query is correct by verifying the result with print(c.fetchone()).

```
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = ?)", (icaocode,))
result = c.fetchone()
if result is True:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("SELECT ICAO FROM airports WHERE ICAO = ?)", (icaocode,))
result = c.fetchone()
if result:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

If no row is found, `fetchone` returns `None`. If a row is found, then `fetchone` will return the row as a non-empty tuple, whose bool value would therefore be Truish.

Comment: I changed it to "if not result is None". Now, the result always is Found.

Comment: Print `result`. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm confused... How do I test if the return of a query is true or false? With my original code, print(c.fetchall()) prints either (1,) or (0,). However, my if/else statement always prints "Not found...", regardless of the query result.